# Flatbuffers - struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes

Tags: python, deserialization, unpack, flatbuffers

I have a server that is sending continuous flatbuff data on a port, I am using python socket to collect the data and de-serialize them. When I try to access the data using `dataOut.Id()` it throws below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/Flatbuf_data/Read_Flatbuf_Data.py", line 45, in <module>
    Id = dataOut.Id()   File "/home/user/Flatbuf_data/Trval.py", line 25, in Id
    o = flatbuffers.number_types.UOffsetTFlags.py_type(self._tab.Offset(4))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flatbuffers/table.py",
line 37, in Offset
    vtable = self.Pos - self.Get(N.SOffsetTFlags, self.Pos)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flatbuffers/table.py", line
93, in Get
    return flags.py_type(encode.Get(flags.packer_type, self.Bytes, off))   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flatbuffers/encode.py", line
26, in Get
    return packer_type.unpack_from(memoryview_type(buf), head)[0] struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes
```

Here is the snippet of the code I am using, I have tried the code with both versions 2.7 & 3.6 and get the same error

```
import socket
import Trval    # Generated from fbs file. This file is generated with flatc --python <filename>.fbs command
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((hostname, port))
data = s.recv(1024)   # unsure what value to give, hence given 1024 as example value
time.sleep(1)
print("Connection closed.")
s.close()

byte_Data = bytearray(data)  # converting bytes to bytearray type"
dataOut = Trval.Trval.GetRootAsTrval(byte_Data, 0)
Id = dataOut.Id()   # Getting error here
print(Id)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am following steps as per the [Flatbuffers-Python](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_python.html) tutorial. Could any one help me resolving this issue

Comment: There is no legal FlatBuffer that fits in <4 bytes, so it sounds like you have corrupt data. Not familiar with that Python networking code, but a FlatBuffer is binary data, so that `utf-8` in there looks very suspect..

Comment: @Aardappel I did try removing utf-8, still the same error. I am receiving bytes as data from socket, that i am now converting into bytearray, the code above is updated